# Setting up different tab navigation depending on view Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, tabs

I have a tricky problem (or at least I think its tricky). I have set up tabs in ionic by having a menu view with an associated abstract route.

menu.html:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-custom">
  <!-- Add Back Button Directive -->
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>

</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-stable tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="app.headlines">
      <ion-nav-view name="dashboard"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Portfolio" icon="ion-arrow-graph-up-right" ui-sref="app.stocks">
      <ion-nav-view name="portfolio"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Alerts" icon="ion-ios-bolt" ui-sref="app.alerts">
      <ion-nav-view name="alerts"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Saved" icon="ion-bookmark" ui-sref="app.saved-posts">
      <ion-nav-view name="saved"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Accounts" icon="ion-gear-a" ui-sref="app.accounts">
      <ion-nav-view name="accounts"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-nav-view>
```

piece of routes.js:

```
angular.module('starter')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            cache: false
        })
```

The tabs work beautifully and just as I would expect. The next step is to change what those tab options are depending on what view I currently am on. So for example instead of Dashboard, Portfolio, Alerts, Saved, Accounts, that I have set as a default, I want options that will lead to foo, bar and foo2. What is the best approach to accomplish this? I have read a little on nested tabs but I don't think that is the way to go (seems to be for having tabs on top of tabs or something).